# Remove specific forgein keys in Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following two models

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    mod_desc = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    another_desc = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    modone = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne)
```

And the following admin code for ModelTwoAdmin

```
class ModelTwoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self,db_field,request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'modone':
            kwargs['queryset'] = ModelOne.objects.exclude(is_active=False)

    fieldsets = [
        ('String 1', {'fields' : ['another_desc','modone']}),
        ('String 2', {'fields' : ['is_active']}),
    ]
```

My goal is to filter out ModelOne entries where `is_active` is `False`. However, the above code returns an error - line 7 is highlighted in the stack trace but in code blocks here is surrounded with `**`:

```
Django Version:     1.4
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:    

"Key 'modone' not found in Form"

Exception Location:     c:\Python\Python2.7\App\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py in __getitem__, line 109

1   <fieldset class="module aligned {{ fieldset.classes }}">
2   {% if fieldset.name %}<h2>{{ fieldset.name }}</h2>{% endif %}
3   {% if fieldset.description %}
4   <div class="description">{{ fieldset.description|safe }}</div>
5   {% endif %}
6   {% for line in fieldset %}
**7     <div class="form-row{% if line.fields|length_is:'1' and line.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% for field in line %}{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">**
8   {% if line.fields|length_is:'1' %}{{ line.errors }}{% endif %}
9   {% for field in line %}
10  <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="field-box{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}"{% endif %}>
11  {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
12  {% if field.is_checkbox %}
13  {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
14  {% else %}
15  {{ field.label_tag }}
16  {% if field.is_readonly %}
17  <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>
```

How can I filter out the inactive `ModelOne`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return statement was missing from the `formfield_for_foreignkey` method. The return statement should be:

```
return super(ModelTwo, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you specified a `None` fieldset twice. The second one is overriding the first, so the only field in your form is `is_active`. Give the second `None` an actual string name, or just combine the two fieldsets into one.

Comment: I tried (and edited my answer to reflect what I tried). The error didn't change at all.

Comment: Are you using `runserver` or another webserver?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code at this point. Try actually quitting `runserver` and then starting it up again. You might also try deleting the `admin.pyc` file there. Turn any caching you have off (set cache backend to DummyCache if it's not already).

Comment: D'oh! Forgot the return statement:  `return super(ModelTwo, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)`

Comment: Sheesh. And, I didn't notice it either. It's always the little things. Add that as an answer and accept it when you can.